# Naming Windows System Image

Tags: windows-7, backup, windows-backup

Is there a option to name/rename folder (actual image) that is created with "Backup and Restore\ Create a System image" when you backup your system. I'm unable to find any naming options. It appears that where is no way to do that. I have a couple of different OS images and would like to give them custom names to better differentiate them.

I'm using Windows Ultimate 7/64 bit.

Thanks.

Comment: You can rename any file after it is created, your question makes no sense.

Comment: Will restore work if I rename file?

Comment: Sure will, the name does not affect how restore works.